# Jquery validação

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando resolver um problema de validação usando o Jquery ,porem não posso usar a própria lib do jquery para fazer essa validação.

Até o momento eu consegui fazer uma validação usando só o jquery ,porém me deparei com o seguinte problema ,quando usuário não preenche o campo de tempo,aparece a msg "Campo Obrigatório" do lado do campo de tempo ,mas quando vou dar submit novamente com o campo não preenchido ,ele repete a msg novamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo do Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#region_btnSave').click(function ()
    {  
        var txtHValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").val();
        var emailAddressValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").val();
        if (emailAddressValue == '' || txtHValue == '') {
            $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").after('<span class="error">Campo Obrigadorio</span>',null);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            //not all text fields are valid
            $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").after('', null);
        }
    });
});
```

Campo de validação:

```
<td> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtH" runat="server" MaxLength="3" Width="40" />
    <span class="error"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Se possível coloque o código html completo.

Comment: As vezes isso esta relacionado a arquivos duplicados, ou um jquery ou o seu próprio arquivo de javascript, tenta verificar o código em uma outra pagina independente e limpa de scripts, se o erro não ocorrer, é algum arquivo duplicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema da repetição está relacionado com esta linha:

```
$("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").after('<span class="error">Campo Obrigadorio</span>',null);
```

Onde `.after` adiciona o elemento após o `$("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH")`.

Vou usar um exemplo do que pode ser feito, mas pode não ser a melhor opção no seu caso, pois o código html não está completo.

Nesta parte modifique:

```
<span class="error" id="errortxtH"></span>
```

E nesta aqui modifique estas linhas:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#region_btnSave').click(function ()
    {  
        var txtHValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").val();
        var emailAddressValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").val();
        if (emailAddressValue == '' || txtHValue == '') {
            $("#errortxtH").text("Campo Obrigatorio");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            //not all text fields are valid
            $("#errortxtH").text("");
        }
    });
});
```

Foi utilizado a função [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) do jquery, para colocar o conteúdo(Campo obrigatório) no `<span>` e lembrando que este código apenas adiciona campo obrigatório para o input tempo de curso.

Veja se isso resolve a tua dúvida.

Comment: Deu certo,muito obrigado!

Comment: saberia me dizer se tem como fazer esse mesmo codigo com ajax para assim que ele colocar coisa no campo ,o span some

Comment: Com ajax teria que dar uma olhada, mas pode ser feito via evento onkeydown por exemplo, quando a primeira tecla for digitada no input, realiza o evento X que apaga o conteúdo do <span>.

Comment: @RobsonOliveira Caso você esteja usando asp você pode utilizar a função .change que deverá dar certo. Qualquer coisa abra outra pergunta.

Comment: To conseguindo fazer com keydown ,estou usando sim asp porem nessa tela acaba qeu a validação do asp não funciona,por isso que estou tendo que fazer com o jquery(já é um sistema que existia )